# Get invoking shortcut

Tags: windows, qt, sdk, desktop, shortcut

Need to retrieve the path of an invoking shortcut.

This is a Qt application, but I suspect I'm going to have to go native to do this, primarily on win.  I can come up with a scheme for Mac..

Is there a way to get this? The win terminal application seems to be able to do this, for instance.

(it needs to work for a moved shortcut, so I can't embed the path in an arg.)

Answer (score 0):

When a process is started, there is no information passed that identifies the shortcut that was used to invoke the new process.  You need to use command-line arguments to pass startup parameters to the new process.

Comment: Again, it needs to work for a moved shortcut, so embedding the location information in the command-line arts (if this is what you're advocating) doesn't work - there's no way for the shortcut to update itself on move.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to search the hard-drive for the named .lnk file (I do know this, unless the user changed it, of course.). Hmmm.  Even if they changed it, I could parse the args in the .lnk files and identify it.  Searching the whole drive is not an attractive proposition...

Comment: Clearly the design of whatever you are doing is deeply flawed. But you didn't tell us what you are doing. The fact that you have asked so many questions but failed to accept a single one and voted only once is not a good sign.

Comment: Correct statements that provide no suggestion or solution aren't useful and get no votes.

Comment: We can't help until you tell us the problem. You ask for solutions but fail to present the problem.